# typo3 rtehtml upscaling images

Tags: typo3, rte

I am trying to upscaling an image which is inserted into the rte in Typo3 with the image button. 
If I change the width to a lower one, it is working fine. Height is choosen automatically. But if I try to increase the width, the rte only save this changes if I manually add the right height.

In my PageTS I already have this:

```
RTE.default.buttons.image.options {
        magic.maxWidth = 1000
        magic.maxHeight = 1000
        plain.maxWidth = 1000
        plain.maxHeight = 1000
    }
```

I configured

```
TYPO3_CONF_VARS[GFX][im_noScaleUp] = 0
```

Has anyone an idea if this is a bug? How can I make typo3 to upscale the image?

Comment: May I ask why you'd want to upscale images instead of just using CSS? The default TS behavior is to never upscale which in my opinion is perfectly reasonable?

Comment: the pictures should not be always same width. and its not ts its the rte, i can insert higher width value but it just dont save it.